# Return a numpy array, with numbers of elements specified in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have two numpy arrays `A`, `B`, with `A.shape = (2,4,3)` and `B.shape = (2,4)`:

```
A =
[[[-1 -1  0]
  [-1  0  0]
  [-1  0  0]
  [ 0 -1  0]]

 [[-1  0  0]
  [-1  0  0]
  [-1  1  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]]

B = 
[[0 2 0 3]
 [1 0 0 0]]
```

Now I would like to get a new array `C` with `C.shape = (2+3+1,3) = (6,3)`, such that each integer in `B` specifies the number of the corresponding 3x1 array in `A`. In other words, `A[i,j,:]` should appear `B[i,j]` times in `C`. In our case,

```
C = 
[[-1  0  0]
 [-1  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  0]
 [ 0 -1  0]
 [ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  0  0]]
```

What is the fastest way to obtain `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of doing this by reshaping `A` into a simple 2D array of which the rows `A[i]`, are to be repeated according to the count in `B[i]`.

Note that `B` is also flattened to be a 1D array.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[[-1, -1,  0],
  [-1,  0,  0],
  [-1,  0,  0],
  [ 0, -1,  0]],

 [[-1,  0,  0],
  [-1,  0,  0],
  [-1,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  0,  0]]])

B = np.array([[0, 2, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 0, 0]])

A = A.reshape(-1, A.shape[2]) # A.shape becomes (8, 3)
B = B.reshape(-1)             # B.shape becomes (8, )

C = np.repeat(A, B, axis = 0)
>>>C
```

Output:

```
array([[-1,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0]])
```

[Here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is how `np.repeat()` works, in case you need reference.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works beautifully when dimensions of A and B are large.